# Typescript Interface get value from other field within same interface as Angular 2 String interpolation doesn't support or and | operator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I just want to know, is it possible to do like below

```
export interface CommonInputProp{
   id:Number;
   value?:String;
   displayName?:String;
   order?:Number;
   viewVal:String=this.value|this.displayName; // This is not supported now
}
```

does it have any alternative ?
I am not implementing this interface, simple using it to get/map response and 
to read value.

Reason , I am doing this, **Angular 2 String Interpolation** doesn't support or and | operator and POJO with I am dealing is instance of Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options:

```
export class CommonInputProp {
   id:Number;
   value?:String;
   displayName?:String;
   order?:Number;
   get viewVal():String { return this.value || this.displayName; }
}

let commonInputProp = new CommonInputProp();
commonInputProp.value = 'test';
commonInputProp.viewVal === 'test' //You can use viewVal as a property
```

Or with your interface you could do:

```
{{ commonInputProp.value || commonInputProp.displayName }}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/JRORVnni9plBRlXoSzI1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, This is  what I want.